# Rails highlight table row if date created more than 6 months?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, html-table

I am working on a rails 2.3 application to simplify internal paperwork creation etc. We have cases that get assigned to particular people but there is a time restraint of 6 months that the case has to be resolved or cancelled.

I have a table of cases (the Rails model is called Kases) which is like so:

```
<!-- START KASE SUB CONTENT -->
<div id="kase_subcontent">
<% unless Kase.most_recentfive.empty? %>

<div id="kasecounts">
    <ul>
        <li>Active Cases: <strong><%= @kases_active_count %></strong></li>
        <li>On Hold: <strong><%= @kases_on_hold_count %></strong></li>
        <li>Archived: <strong><%= @kases_archived_count %></strong></li>
        <li>Invoice Sent: <strong><%= @kases_invoice_sent_count %></strong></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<table class="index">
  <tr>
    <th>Job Ref.</th>
    <th>Subject</th>
    <th>Transport</th>
    <th>Client</th>
    <th>Client Ref.</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>

<% for kase in @kases %>

    <tr class="<%= cycle("even", "odd") %> <%=h kase.kase_status %>" onclick="location.href='<%= kase_path(kase) %>'">
  <td><%=h kase.jobno %></td>
    <td><%=h kase.casesubject %></td>
    <td><%=h kase.transport %></td>
    <td><%=h kase.company.companyname %></td>
    <td><%=h kase.clientref %></td>
    <td><%=h kase.kase_status %></td>

<!--    
    <td><%= link_to "Jobsheet", kase_path(kase, :format => 'pdf'), :class => 'PDFLink' %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', kase %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_kase_path(kase) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', kase, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete, :class => 'important' %></td>
-->
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<% else %>

<img src="images/allcases-sample.jpg" />

<% end %>
```

When the user creates a new case then set the date of 'instruction' (case received) like so:

```
<li>Date Instructed<span><%= f.date_select :dateinstructed, :order => [:day, :month, :year] %></span></li>
```

They can also, at any point, alter the 'status' of the case like so:

```
<li>Current Case Status<span><%= f.select "kase_status", ['Active', 'On Hold', 'Archived', 'Invoice Sent'] %></span></li>
```

What I would like to do is highlight the table rows for cases that are currently Active and the date of instruction was more than 6 months ago.

I have set basic styling for archived cases (faded the colour) but I think it would be useful to make the rows red for anything that is becoming urgent. So I may cases older than 5 months amber and then 6 months red.

An extra bonus would be to somehow make the row blink so it's obvious to the user.

Any idea how to do this?

---

**UPDATE**

I have added the following to the kase helper:

```
def is_urgent
  if (DateTime.now - 180) > @dateinstructed then
    content_tag(:class => "urgentCase")
  end
end
```

and called it from the view with the following:

```
<%=h is_urgent %>
```

but I get the following error:

> undefined method `to_datetime' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Are you calling the method using kase? kase.is_urgent?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that aswell but still not working.

Comment: Are you assigning the @dateinstructed variable a value at any point?

Comment: The current date is added automatically when a case is made.

Answer (score 0):

CSS classes are space-delimited, so you could provide another method that determines whether the item is 'urgent' or 'critical' and add that style to the table row.
Then all you need to do is add a new style that uses the new classes *under* the old style definition.

```
def is_urgent
    (DateTime.now - 180) > @dateinstructed
end
```

Comment: I have updated my question with the results of your method example.